# Composition of cyclic permutation

Tags: group-theory, permutations, cyclic-groups

I have a permutation $ \alpha = (125)(1378)(12546)(126) $. I know that I have to follow this rule when calculating permutation in their cyclic form: Ex for the first term
$$ 1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 5\rightarrow 5 \rightarrow 1$$ So 1 goes to 1, which I can omit. Then the same rule applies for 2 and so on. When I calculate $\alpha$ like this I get this result: $\alpha = (2378)(465)$. Anyway I use this [calculator](http://www.bananattack.com/permutations/) to ensure that my result is right, which unfortunately it is not the case. The right answer is (15378624). So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: That online calculator seems to compose cycles in reverse order.  Entering `(126)*(12546)*(1378)*(125)` gives your correct result.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your replay. I have also tryied to compute this permutation in the standar notation(i.e. the permutation (125) is written as 
$ \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 &8 \\ 
2 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 7 &8
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr) $ 
And this time I get the result  (16543782)